# CSS and Wordpress: remove padding from element

Tags: css, wordpress

I've built a page using Wordpress, and am now trying to modify is using CSS.  I want to remove the top padding from a particular element on my page.  After inspecting the culprit element (using Chrome-->Inspect Element), I see that it has a class of .content-area and a top-padding of 72px.  Here is the relevant CSS info yielded by inspect element:

```
.content-area, .content-sidebar {
padding-top: 72px;
}
```

However, when I insert the following into my style.css:

```
.content-area{
padding-top: 0px;
}
```

the padding remains.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong, or how to resolve?

Comment: Use the same selector to overwrite it. Specificity is the issue here.. `.content-area, .content-sidebar {
padding-top: 0;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did that, but to no avail.  I inserted the following into my CSS:

.content-area, .content-sidebar {
padding-top: 0px;
}

But the padding remains.

How do I format something as bold in this comment?  I tried putting the code in backticks, but nothing happened.

Comment: Then the order they appear in the stylesheet is the issue. Make sure you place it after/below the selector you are trying to overwrite. Stylesheets are read from top to bottom (cascade). And I didn't even see the comma `,` in the selector. Specificity isn't the issue then.

Comment: I am reasonably sure I am placing this new code below the selector.  I am inserting this new code into a .css file (style.css) that is called after the page is created.  i.e. the page is created, in-part with the selector that gives this certain element a top padding of 72px.  Then my style sheet is called, which should override it.  Maybe that is not happening for some reason?

Comment: It's not recommended, but have you tried putting padding-top: 0px !important; instead? It will force it to remove the padding-top for the element.

Comment: Adding the !important did not help either.  Something that may be pertinent is that, when I do an inspect element on the element in-question, the FULL information given is:

media="all"
@media screen and (min-width: 846px)
.content-area, .content-sidebar {
padding-top: 72px;
}

Does this change things?

Comment: Let me investigate this media query stuff and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

sometime time this property can be inherited by parent class so you can try to this code

```
 .content-area, .content-sidebar {
        padding-top: 72px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  I changed the CSS to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 846px) {
    .content-area {
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

and the padding disappeared.  Other media queries in CSS aren't as intuitive, but at least this works for now.